# Rest easy JQUERY 404

Tags: jquery, rest, jboss7.x, resteasy

I did a REST service in JBoss 7 env. using javax.ws.rs.core.Application and using @ApplicationPath like the guides suggest.

So the follow REST Service's code should be correct and the paths too:

```
@Path(value="/service") 
@ApplicationPath("/app")  

public class MioRESTserv extends Application {  


      @GET
       @Path(value="/echo/{message}")
       public String answer(@PathParam(value="message") String message) {
          return "Answer " + message;
       }

       @POST
       @Path(value="/ordering")
       @Consumes(value="application/json")
       @Produces(value="application/xml")
       public Output ordering(Input input) {
          Arrays.sort(input.getVector());
          return new Output(input.getVector());
       }
    }
```

The first Rest service "answer" working ok. But when I try, testing the POST REST service  "ordering"  using JQuery in the following html page  (used  like consumer)  i have wrong rensponse(SEE BELOW) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "input[type=submit]" ).click(function(event) {   //$('#submit').click(function() {
            var string = $('#numbers').val();
            if (string.indexOf(',') != -1) {  alert("in " + string);

            $.post({  
                    url: "http://localhost:8090/PAX_IN_REST/app/service/sorting",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: '{"vector" : [' + string + ']}',                  
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert("errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
                    }
                }); 
            } else {
                alert('Bad format! Must be x,y,z');
            }
        });
});
```

The paths are correct.  If I test "bad format" , it is working good too . With correct input (digiting for example 1, 3,6,7,2)  the "ordering" RESTService , with `type=POST`  or `method=POST`, Answer by alert is: `404 The requested resource (/REST_IN_PAX/[object%20Object]) is not available`.

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: I'd like to add on that the code posted here is with $post statement and , so, i have not put in the type or method property like, instead, the $.ajax statement needs.

Comment: About the path:  I used http://localhost:8090/PAX_IN_REST/app/service/ordering. But the problem still persist.

Comment: Setting alert(data.sortedVector.toString()); inside  the function success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  }   but the issue don't change.

Answer (score 0):

You really want a separate file for your `@ApplicationPath` annotation:

```
/**
 * Let the container know that we have a JAX-RS application.
 */
@ApplicationPath("/app")
public class AppResources extends Application {

}
```

And then a seperate file for your resource:

```
@Path("/service") 
public class MioRESTserv {  

   @GET
   @Path(value="/echo/{message}")
   public String answer(@PathParam(value="message") String message) {
      return "Answer " + message;
   }

   @POST
   @Path(value="/ordering")
   @Consumes(value="application/json")
   @Produces(value="application/xml")
   public Output ordering(Input input) {
      Arrays.sort(input.getVector());
      return new Output(input.getVector());
   }
}
```

You might like to check out this link to help you get started: http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial